# returning null when the array is outside the desired range

Tags: java, arrays, output

Say I have a function that produces an array:

```
static long[] solveEquationB(int x, int j) 
{  
    long[] e = new long[j];
    for (int i = 1; i < j; i++)
    {
       x = 1.0*x/(2.0) + 3 ;
       e[i] = x;
    }
    return e;
}
```

How can I get the output to produce `null` when `j < 0`?

Comment: `if (j < 0) return null;`

Comment: before the array inizialitation yuo can check j, if j<0 return null else your code

Comment: Note that for Collection classes it is considered good practice to return an empty collection rather than null, I guess the same applies for arrays as well even if I have never come across it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test `j` before creating the array:

```
static long [] solveEquationB (int x, int j) 
{  
    long[] e = null;
    if (j >= 0) { // or perhaps > 0 if you don't want to return an empty array
        e = new long[j];
        for (int i = 1; i < j; i++)
        {
            x = 1.0*x/(2.0) + 3 ;
            e[i] = x;
        }
    }
    return e;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add one line as a ternary operator check to the above code. Here's the modified code:

```
static long[] solveEquationB(int x, int j) {  
     long[] e = j > 0? new long[j]: null;
     for (int i = 1; i < j; i++) {
        x = 1.0*x/(2.0) + 3 ;
        e[i] = x;
     }

     return e;
 }
```